# Is torsion of a multivariate curve defined in n-dimensional space?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, curves, applications

I understand that torsion is a concept specific to three-dimensional spaces. Despite searching on Google, I've struggled to find how to extend the concept of torsion to an n-dimensional space.

Is it not feasible to adapt torsion for higher dimensions, or is there a formula in the academic literature that addresses this? I also looked for references on this topic but couldn't find any.

Comment: It is hard to believe that a google search won't find torsion in differential geometry.

Comment: @KurtG. Although I agree with you, I'm not sure exactly how torsion for affine connections is linked to the torsion of curves in $\Bbb R^3$, which is what I presume OP refers to

Comment: @KurtG. I think you misunderstood my post or maybe I wasn't clear. The torsion defined in a 3d space (7d too) can be found on google. I'm talking about generalizing the concept of torsion to any dimensional space (n-d). As a beginner in differential geometry, I may not have been able to identify this generalization in the literature. If you have references or libraries that have already developed this concept generalized to n-d space, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: This [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20493/what-is-torsion-in-differential-geometry-intuitively) discusses it. What is your understanding of torsion in 3D and 7D?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> _Torsion_ means multiple things in differential geometry. Can you please edit the question to clarify if you're asking about "torsion of a connection," "torsion of a space curve," or something else?

Comment: @KurtG. In my case, I am interested in the torsion of multivariate curves. Here, torsion corresponds to the rotation speed of the binormal vector at a given point. This definition is true for 3D. For 7D, what I understood is that torsion is how much a curve deviates from lying in a 6-dimensional hyperplane at a given point. My view of torsion is the one explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIqA8U9ozIA)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I am rather interested in the torsion of curves in the context of the Frenet Frame

Comment: If memory serves, there is a complete account in either volume 2 or (likelier?) 3 of Spivak's _Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry_; the general idea is to define (an orthonormal generalization of) the Frenet frame recursively so that the derivative of the unit velocity $e_1$ lies in the plane spanned by $\{e_1, e_2\}$, the derivative of $e_2$ lies in the three-space spanned by $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$, and so forth.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1950720/definition-of-frenet-frame-for-curves-in-mathbbrn/1950797#1950797) and particularly [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697388/frenet-serret-formulas-in-arbitrary-dimensions/1697412#1697412).